# Creating a dynamic memory in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a dynamic memory. The size of the array is determine by the user input. I'm getting the following error, 
`"expression must have a constant value"`.

it seems like I'm doing something wrong. Please help me! How can I make this dynamic?

This is what I have so far:

```
int* IntPtr = NULL;
int main(){

 int arraySize;
 cout << "How many numbers will be on the list? ";
 cin >> arraySize;

 IntPtr = new int[arraySize];

Contact list[arraySize]; // <-- expression must be constant

//more code

delete [] IntPtr;
```

Comment: ¤ Use a `std::vector<Contact>` instead. Then you do not even need to know the final size. You can just ask the user for another number, and use the `push_back` method to add it to the vector, which then grows as necessary. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use [Variable Length Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Unfortunately, C++ does not allow them. (though some compiles allow them by extension)

What you need instead is to dynamically allocate the array using `new`. (and manually deallocate later with `delete`)

You're already doing this correctly with:

```
IntPtr = new int[arraySize];
```

Now you can do the same with the `list` variable:

```
Contact *list = new Contact[arraySize];
delete [] list;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `vector` class, which is often preferred over dynamic arrays.

```
vector<Contact> list(arraySize);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an [`std::vector<Contact>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) instead, or if you want to allocate a bare array do the same as you do with `IntPtr`:

```
Contact* list = new Contact[arraySize];
```